# Get entry point script file location in setuputils package?

Tags: python, setuptools

So I have an entry point defined in my setup.py [console_scripts] section. The command is properly installed and works fine, but I need a way to programatically find out the path to the script (e.g. on windows it'll be something like C:/my/virtual/env/scripts/my_console_script.exe). I need this so I can pass that script path as an argument to other commands, regardless of where the package is installed. Setuputils provides the `pkg_resources`, but that doesn't seem to expose any way of actually getting at the raw installed paths, only loadable objects.

Edit: To make the use case plain here's the setup.

I have a plugin-driven application that communicates with various local services. One of these plug-ins ties into the alerting interface of an NMS package. The only way this alerting package can get alerts out to an arbitrary handler is to call a script - the path to execute (the console_scripts entry point in this case) is register as a complete path - that's the path I need to get.

Comment: Can you find the path of the script based on knowing the real path to a site-packages package, or some other directory? If not do you control the installer for the script? Also is it only Windows we are talking about? Is the directory the script is located in pointed to by the PATH variable, or other environment variable?

Comment: I can't get the installed path from setuptools. The binary path is PROBABLY not on the system PATH, as the typical install will be to a virtualenv. Windows support is required but the code will be running on *nix as well.

Comment: you mention .exe; for windows are you using py2exe?

Comment: When you say 'dynamic' here, it sounds a lot more like 'magic' in that unless it's defined in the path, or in the same working dir of the script you have to do a lot of guess work.  Have you considered using a variable that you pipe into the setup.py script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could pass an option of the form `--install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"` to `pip` and just set the path yourself. But I understand why you might not want to hardcode that in a cross-platform project.

So, we just need to find out what directory `setuptools` is *actually* using. Unfortunately, the path is determined in the middle of a whole bunch of actual setup code, rather than in a separate function we can just call.

So the next step is to write a custom install command that observes and saves the path. (For that matter, you could also *set* `self.install_scripts` to a directory of your choice in this custom installer class, thereby keeping that piece of config in one place (the package) rather than in the package and in a command line arg to setup...)

Example:

```python
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from distutils.command.build_py import build_py
import os

class InstallReadsScriptDir(install):
    def run(self):
        self.distribution._x_script_dir = self.install_scripts
        install.run(self)

class BuildConfiguresScriptDir(build_py):
    def run(self):
        build_py.run(self)
        if self.dry_run:
            return
        script_dir = self.distribution._x_script_dir  # todo: check exists
        target = os.path.join(self.build_lib, 'mypackage', 'scriptdir.py')
        with open(target, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('path = """{}"""'.format(script_dir))

setup(
    name="MyPackage",
    version='0.0.1',
    packages = ['mypackage'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'footest = mypackage:main',
        ],
    },
    cmdclass= {
        'install': InstallReadsScriptDir,
        'build_py': BuildConfiguresScriptDir,
    },
)
```

Possible objections:

- Some people don't like any form of code generation. In this case it's more like configuration, though putting it in a `.py` in the package makes it easy to get at from Python code anywhere.
- On the surface it looks like a bit of a hack. However, `setuptools` is specifically designed to allow custom command classes. Nothing here is really accessing anything private, except maybe the value passing using the `distribution` object which is just to avoid a `global`.
- Only gets the directory, not the executable names. You should know the names though, based on your entry point configuration. Getting the names would require calling the parsing methods for your entry point spec and generating more code.
- It's going to need some bugfixing if you e.g. build without installing. `sdist` is safe though.
- `develop` is possible but needs another command class. `install` isn't called and `build_py` is only called if you set `use_2to3`. A custom `develop` command can get the path as in the `install` example, but as `self.script_dir`. From there you have to decide if you're comfortable writing a file to your source directory, which is in `self.egg_path` -- as it will get picked up by `install` later, though it should be the same file (and the build command will overwrite the file anyway)

**Addendum**

This little flash of insight may be more elegant as it does not require saving the path anywhere, but still gets the actual path setuptools uses, though of it assumes no configuration has changed since the install.

```python
from setuptools import Distribution
from setuptools.command.install import install

class OnlyGetScriptPath(install):
    def run(self):
        # does not call install.run() by design
        self.distribution.install_scripts = self.install_scripts

def get_setuptools_script_dir():
    dist = Distribution({'cmdclass': {'install': OnlyGetScriptPath}})
    dist.dry_run = True  # not sure if necessary, but to be safe
    dist.parse_config_files()
    command = dist.get_command_obj('install')
    command.ensure_finalized()
    command.run()
    return dist.install_scripts
```

**Addendum 2**

Just realized/remembered that `pip` creates an `installed-files.txt` in the `egg-info`, which is a list of paths relative to the package root of all the files including the scripts. `pkg_resources.get_distribution('mypackage').get_metadata('installed-files.txt')` will get this. It's only a `pip` thing though, not created by `setup.py install`. You'd need to go through the lines looking for your script name and then get the absolute path based on your package's directory.

Comment: Ok, I feel this is really close, so I've marked it accepted for now. Any way to make this work with 'develop' as well?

Comment: Your addendum is the solution I needed to install a binary in the path of the environment, for both `install` and `develop` commands (as `install_scripts` is only available as a member of the command class in the `install` scenario).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `os.path.abspath(__file__)' in your entry point script? It'll return yours entry point absolute path.

Or call `find_executable` from `distutils.spawn`:

`import distutils.spawn
distutils.spawn.find_executable('executable')`

Comment: Not an option because the script exists outside the library folder, and in any case the entry point script isn't where I need to load the location.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the path for site_packages directory as follows:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
get_python_lib()
```

If your script is somewhere relative to that path, either in site-packages or up a directory you could then join the relative path with the site-packages path as follows:

```
import os
scriptPath = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(get_python_lib(), '../my/relative/path/script.exe'))
```

Another trick you could try is to import the associated module and then look at its **file** parameter. You could then look for your script the same way as the example above if you know what the relative path is to that file. Try it on the command line interface..

```
import django
django.__file__
```

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/**init**.pyc

```
modulePath = os.path.split(django.__file__)[0]
scriptPath = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(modulePath, '../my/relative/path/script.exe'))
```

Is the above advice on the right track?

Comment: Not an option because the script exists outside the library folder, and in any case the entry point script isn't where I need to load the location. Setuptools scripts are special launch wrappers and not directly importable.

Comment: @TylerEaves Where exactly are you trying to get the path that you need.  I think you need to update your question with more detail in order for people to really help you.