# Python setuptools installing script to path

Tags: python, setuptools

My Python module contains an external script that users can execute from the command line. I'd like users to be able to install the Python module and script all in one go. Using setuptools, I have tried adding:

```
scripts=['bin/mybin']
```

which almost does the trick. Instead of adding `mybin` to the user's PATH, it adds a small script that calls `mybin`:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'myscript==2.0.4','mybin'
__requires__ = 'myscript==2.0.4'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('myscript==2.0.4', 'mybin')
```

This indirection is causing some problems, notably a small lag when the script is executed (compared to copying `mybin` to the PATH directly).

Is there any way to have setuptools copy the script directly to the PATH rather than have it call my script indirectly?

My first thought is to write a custom [post-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) function to copy the script to the user's path. But if there is a way to do this natively in setuptools, I would prefer that.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to add this to your `setup.py`:

```
  data_files=[
    ('/usr/local/bin', ['bin/mybin'])
    ]
```

which copies `bin/mybin` to `/usr/local/bin`.

Another solution that does not require hard-coding a bin directory is to first detect the script directory that setuptools *would* copy your script to, then use `data_files` to copy it there directly. [This StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176606/353278) answer explains how to detect the setuptools script path.